# Cannot read section from app.config

Tags: c#, .net, app-config, configsection

I have a simple config section as follows

```
<configuration>
    <configSections>
        <section name="Test" type="System.Configuration.DictionarySectionHandler"/>
        <section name="Test1" type="System.Configuration.DictionarySectionHandler"/>
    </configSections>
    <Test>
        <add key="foo" value="1"/>
    </Test>
    <Test1>
        <add key="bar" value="20"/>
    </Test1>
</configuration>
```

And I am accessing it from code as

```
var blah = ConfigurationManager.GetSection("Test");
```

But I always get null. I tried everything but could not figure out whats going on. Could someone please help me with this?

Thanks,

Comment: Is this a DLL project or an EXE project?

Comment: It works for me. When I debug it, `blah` is of type `HashTable` and `blah["foo"] == 1`. What if you use `Hashtable blah = (Hashtable)ConfigurationManager.GetSection("Test")`?

Comment: The config is in a console app project and the reading code in a class library. but I tried read it from the console app as well and got the same result.